# Jenkins CascadeChoiceParameter causes MissingPropertyException: No such property

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have (in this simplified example) two dynamic parameters in my Jenkinsfile, the first one is a `ChoiceParameter`, the second one is a `CascadeChoiceParameter`, depending on the first one.

The code below shows these two parameters `CATEGORY` and `USER` in my Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'CATEGORY',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [ classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: 
                    """
                    return ['one', 'two']
                    """
                ]
            ]
        ],

        [
            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            referencedParameters: 'CATEGORY',
            name: 'USER',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [ classpath: [], sandbox: true, script:
                    """
                    if ( CATEGORY.equals( 'one' ) ) {
                        return ['user for category one']
                    } else {
                        return ['user for category two']
                    }
                    """
                ]
            ]
        ],

    ])
])
```

They do work (that is, the second one `USER` changes depending on the first one `CATEGORY`), but also producing the following exception in the Jenkins log:

```
Error executing script for dynamic parameter
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CATEGORY for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    [...]
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to evaluate script: No such property: CATEGORY for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript.eval(GroovyScript.java:197)
    at org.biouno.unochoice.util.ScriptCallback.call(ScriptCallback.java:96)
    [...]
```

I tried to modify the IF-statement of the second groovy script from

```
if ( CATEGORY.equals( 'one' ) ) {
```

to

```
if ( "${CATEGORY}".equals( 'one' ) ) {
```

This eliminates the exception, but (using a Logger) shows that "${CATEGORY}" always evaluates to `"one"`, never to `"two"`, even after changing the dropdown value for the ChoiceParameter "CATEGORY" in the Jenkins UI.

How must I access the parameter `CATEGORY` in the Groovy script to get it working without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work fine for me. Try updating the Plugin maybe.

```
def CATEGORY = ""

properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            name: 'CATEGORY',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [ classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: 
                    """
                    return ['one', 'two']
                    """
                ]
            ]
        ],

        [
            $class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
            referencedParameters: 'CATEGORY',
            name: 'USER',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                script: [ classpath: [], sandbox: true, script:
                    """
                    if ( CATEGORY.equals( 'one' ) ) {
                        return ['user for category one']
                    } else {
                        return ['user for category two']
                    }
                    """
                ]
            ]
        ],

    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
           
        stage('Hello') {

            steps {
                             
                echo 'Hello World'
                println "Category: " + CATEGORY
                println "User: " + USER
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm running Jenkins 2.346.3 with "Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries" version "38.v445716ea_edda_", "Pipeline: Groovy" version "2759.v87459c4eea_ca_" and "Pipeline: Groovy Libraries" version "612.v84da_9c54906d". I tried exactly your Jenkinsfile and still get the exceptions in the Jenkins log.

Comment: @It'sLeto which version of the https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ are you using?

Comment: Do you mean the Active Choices Plugin? I'm using version 2.6.3

Comment: @It'sLeto I'm not sure what's going on, I tried both 2.6.2 and 2.6..4 versions and both seems to work for me. I have slightly modified the Pipeline, can you try it again?