# Jenkins ActiveChoice via Jenkins Input Step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use the [jenkins input step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) to prompt the user dynamic inputs from the [jenkins ActiveChoices plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin)

I have tried to use Jenkins Syntax snippet generator but it seems to crash whenever ActiveChoices is selected.

I have followed up references calling the Jenkins "parameters" for a build with parameters step such as from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74716741/2133078) but referencing this as a drop in replacement for the "parameters" section of input command also doesnt seem to work.

I cant find any references to people using activeChoices directly via the input command mid run. is this supported any ideas?

Example would be

```
def userInput = input(id: 'UserInput', message: 'Select your options:', parameters: [
                        [$class: 'ReactiveChoiceParameter',
                            name: 'FIRST_CHOICE',
                            randomName: 'choice1', // This is typically a generated string for internal use
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                                script: [script: "return ['option1', 'option2']"], // First set of options
                                fallbackScript: [script: "return ['error']"]
                            ],
                            choiceType: 'SINGLE_SELECT',
                            referencedParameters: 'FIRST_CHOICE'
                        ],
                        [$class: 'ActiveChoiceParameter',
                            name: 'SECOND_CHOICE',
                            randomName: 'choice2',
                            script: [
                                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                                script: [
                                    script: """
                                        if (FIRST_CHOICE == 'option1') {
                                            return ['option1.1', 'option1.2']
                                        } else if (FIRST_CHOICE == 'option2') {
                                            return ['option2.1', 'option2.2']
                                        } else {
                                            return ['none']
                                        }
                                    """
                                ],
                                fallbackScript: [script: "return ['error']"]
                            ],
                            choiceType: 'SINGLE_SELECT',
                            filterable: false,
                            filterLength: 1
                        ]
                    ])
```

or a different varient like

```
def userInput = input(id: 'UserInput', message: 'Select your options:', parameters: [
                        activeChoice(name: 'FIRST_CHOICE', 
                                     script: groovyScript(script: "return ['option1', 'option2']"),
                                     choiceType: 'SINGLE_SELECT'),
                        reactiveChoice(name: 'SECOND_CHOICE', 
                                       script: groovyScript(script: """
                                            if (FIRST_CHOICE == 'option1') {
                                                return ['option1.1', 'option1.2']
                                            } else if (FIRST_CHOICE == 'option2') {
                                                return ['option2.1', 'option2.2']
                                            } else {
                                                return ['none']
                                            }
                                       """),
                                       choiceType: 'SINGLE_SELECT',
                                       referencedParameters: 'FIRST_CHOICE')
                    ])
```

Comment: Your issue is still unclear. Can you post Jenkinsfile contents / error messages / screenshots ?